# Entity Framework - How to add db entries without a form

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Usually I add new database entries with a "Create" form, just like the template you are given like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "MyObjectProperties")] MyObject MyObjectName)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.MyObjects.Add(MyObjectName);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(MyObjectName);
}
```

Which works just fine. However, I'm trying to delete all entries in my database and then add them again one by one. The purpose is that the table is filled with deadline dates for each week in a year, and this method will reset the deadlines and set the correct dates for the given year. This is the method that performs that task:

```
public bool ResetDeadlines()
{
    //db.Canteen_Deadlines.RemoveRange(db.Canteen_Deadlines);

    int monthOfLastWeek = 1;
    DateTime deadlineDate;
    int weekOfMonth = 0;
    int year = DateTime.Now.Year;

    for (var i = 1; i < 53; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1)
            year += 1;
        else
            year = DateTime.Now.Year;

        deadlineDate = GetThursdayOfWeek(year, i).AddDays(-7); //Gets the thursday of the week before, because that is the deadline for that week.
        weekOfMonth = monthOfLastWeek < deadlineDate.Month ? 1 : weekOfMonth + 1;

        var newDeadline = new Canteen_Deadlines
        {
            N = DaysFromNewYear(year, deadlineDate),
            DeadlineDate = deadlineDate,
            WeekNo = (byte)i,
            MonthNo = (byte)deadlineDate.Month,
            QuarterNo = (byte)GetQuarterNumber(deadlineDate.Month),
            YearNo = (short)year,
            DayofWeek = 4,
            LastDowInMonth = IsLastDoWInMonth(deadlineDate),
            DoWAsc = (byte)weekOfMonth
        };

        db.Canteen_Deadlines.Add(newDeadline);
        //db.Entry(newDeadline).State = EntityState.Added;
        db.SaveChanges();

        monthOfLastWeek = deadlineDate.Month;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The problem arises when I do `db.SaveChanges();`. It will give me a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`, saying that none of the rows in the database has been affected. I can't seem to figure out the difference between my method and the template create method. Other posts online are more focused on this problem arising when using the template create method and people not using "Html.HiddenFor" on their ID. This is not a viable solution for me, since I am not using a form and therefore have no way of using the Html helper. The user will just press a "Reset deadlines" button.

The "N" property on the objects are their keys. It is the amount of days the given date is into the year, meaning 16th of January would be N = 16. As the deadlines only are for 1 year, the N values will not conflict and therefore should be able to be used as keys.

How can I save these entries in the database successfully? I have commented out the db.remove method, just to get the adding of entries to work. I have also tried setting the entry states to added, but that did not work either. I tried debugging and confirmed that all properties of the object is initialized correctly.

Full exception:

```
[OptimisticConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ValidateRowsAffected(Int64 rowsAffected, UpdateCommand source) +142
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update() +525
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +453
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction) +252
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +206
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction) +270
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +145

[DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +280
   MyProject.Models.Services.DeadlinesService.ResetDeadlines() in \\PROJECTPATH\Models\Services\DeadlinesService.cs:49
   MyProject.Controllers.AdminController.ResetDeadlines() in \\PROJECTPATH\Controllers\AdminController.cs:254
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +87
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +77
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__0() +80
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_2.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +387
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__4() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +188
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +602
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +195
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +128
```

EDIT:
Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult ResetDeadlines()
        {
            deadlinesService.ResetDeadlines();

            return RedirectToAction("IndexDeadlines");
        }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="row" style="margin-left:0px">
            <div>
                <label for="SearchInput" style="font-size:18px">@Res.Search @Res.Week</label>
                @Html.Editor("Search", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus = "autofocus", @id = "SearchInput", @onkeyup = "myFunction()" } })
            </div>
            <div style="margin-left:10px;margin-top:18px">
                <a href="@Url.Action("ResetDeadlines")" class="customBtnXSmall">Reset Deadlines</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

This is the Deadline class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MyProject.Models.DBModels
{
    public class Canteen_Deadlines
    {
        [Key]
        public long? N { get; set; } //Number of days into the year (16th of January is 16 days into the year, so N would be = 16)
        [Column(TypeName = "smalldatetime")]
        public DateTime? DeadlineDate { get; set; }
        public byte? WeekNo { get; set; }
        public byte? MonthNo { get; set; }
        public byte? QuarterNo { get; set; }
        public short YearNo { get; set; }
        public byte? DayofWeek { get; set; }
        public bool? LastDowInMonth { get; set; } //Last DayOfWeek In Month
        public byte? DoWAsc { get; set; } //DayOfWeek Ascending
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After numerous attempts to locate the real issue and with a lot of assistance from @Sergey, I realized that the underlying issue was due to the design of the table in the database and the way Entity Framework 6 works.

**SOLUTION:**

I added a property ID to the `Canteen_Deadlines` class in my code, which is now the key, and added a corresponding column in the database table designer. EF6 now understands that I'm adding new rows and lets the database table assign IDs, so I can assign my own N values.

**BACKGROUND:**

EF6 kept acting like I was trying to update my rows, since N was my key in EF6, which would make sense if it was not for the fact that I'm trying to add rows. Using Microsoft documentation to do a `Try-Catch` on the `UpdateConcurrencyException` confirmed that it was trying to update rows, but could not do it when I'm actually adding them (the new exception was saying that the catch logic would not work with entities in an "*added*" state).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
.....

var deadlines=new List<PP_CanteenScreen_Deadlines>();

for (var i = 1; i < 53; i++)
 {
                if (i == 1)
                    year += 1;
                else
                    year = DateTime.Now.Year;

                deadlineDate = GetThursdayOfWeek(year, i).AddDays(-7); //Gets the thursday 
              //of the week before, because that is the deadline for that week.
                weekOfMonth = monthOfLastWeek < deadlineDate.Month ? 1 : weekOfMonth + 1;

                var newDeadline = new PP_CanteenScreen_Deadlines
                {
                    N = DaysFromNewYear(year, deadlineDate),
                    DeadlineDate = deadlineDate,
                    WeekNo = (byte)i,
                    MonthNo = (byte)deadlineDate.Month,
                    QuarterNo = (byte)GetQuarterNumber(deadlineDate.Month),
                    YearNo = (short)year,
                    DayofWeek = 4,
                    LastDowInMonth = IsLastDoWInMonth(deadlineDate),
                    DoWAsc = (byte)weekOfMonth
                };
                deadlines.Add(newDeadline);
               monthOfLastWeek = deadlineDate.Month;

}
                db.PP_CanteenScreen_Deadlines.AddRange(deadlines);
               var result=  db.SaveChanges();
              if(result < 52) .....your error code

........
```

And I am wondering why you don't try to use auto-increment primary key instead of
public long? N ? Especially I don't like that your primary key is nullable. Is there some reasons for this?

Comment: I'm getting the same exception at "var result = db.SaveChanges();" with your code, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you show How do you call  CanteenBIGScreen.Controllers.AdminController.ResetDeadlines() in \\PROJECTPATH\Controllers\AdminController.cs:254 code pls? The whole action if it is possible.

Comment: I've added the controller action and view page code - I hope that is what you wanted to see.

Comment: @Aletho Thanks, but I am wondering what is this for:  
                Html.Editor("Search", new { htmlAttributes = new { class = "form-control", autofocus = "autofocus", id = "SearchInput", onkeyup = "myFunction()" } }). I mean myFunction?

Comment: And can you show the PP_CanteenScreen_Deadline class pls? Does it have a parent class?

Comment: The "myFunction" is just a script that searches in the table and updates it on keyup so that I do not need a search button. I've added the Deadline class, it does not have a parent class. I have tried to move the "Reset Deadlines" button outside the form html elements, so that should not be the culprit here.

Comment: Did you check N after creating 52 rows.  All N should be unique. I don' t like your algoritm for  N. You have N long so for N you can you can use something like  deadline.TotalDays

Comment: That might do something, but during debugging I get the exception at the first row, so they do not even get the chance to get the same N. Any other ideas?

Comment: When you call savechanges it checks all changes, not just yours.  This error maybe about something else. This is why I am worried about your your search functions.  Dissable everything and just try to save these rows.

Comment: I tried to move the method call to the get request for the index page (so the first thing it does is reset the deadlines), that did not work. I tried calling the method directly through the url path and that did not work either. Is there any other way? I'm trying to avoid having to make an SQL script for my database to do this.

Comment: How do you create and dispose a deadlinesService and a dbcontext? Could you have 2 instances in the same time?

Comment: And  are you sure that your DB don't have any records with the same N key that you are trying to add?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I'm only working part time while studying. I managed to get it to delete all records in the DB through the method, but still with an empty DB, inserting new records does not work. I have looked through the new records and none of them will get the same N key (it increments by 7 every time). I'm trying to perform the action while debugging in Visual Studio, so I doubt there's two instances running - where could I check that?

Comment: The weird thing is that it acts like I'm updating existing rows in the database, but I'm not, I'm adding new rows. I tried using Microsofts documentation of try-catching the updateconcurrency exception and then letting the client values win, but that gives me another exception, because it does not work with the "added" state! I then tried to not give the object an N value if that is what makes it think that I'm talking about specific rows, but that does not work either. This is very frustrating.

Comment: I actually realized the underlying issue as I finished writing my last comment! The problem was a mix of N being the key and my database colleague not defining a primary key in the table designer. I will update with an answer. Thanks for the assistance and spending time problem-solving with me @Sergey!